# how can i shourtcut these functions in to few lines

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I'm writing a code to execute a weighted tree and make all distances of the edges equal , I want to simplify these statements in just a few lines,, to make it more professional any help ???

```
class Node:




def printPostorder(root):
 if root:
    printPostorder(root.left)
    printPostorder(root.right)
    print(root.data, end=' ')
    print(root.weight)  


if root:
    printPostorder(root.left)
    printPostorder(root.right)
    print(root.data, end=' ')
    print(root.weight)  

def new_weights(root):
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation of the *root* class

Comment: i will edit the code to be more clear ,,,class Node

Comment: there is no return condition

Comment: i want to shortcut the def(new_weights ) its just too long

Answer (score 0):

I see many similar code here, lets try to encapsulate it with functions.
Focus on that part

```
    diff=root.right.weight-root.left.weight
    if diff> 0:
        root.left.weight=root.left.weight+ diff
    else:
        root.right.weight=root.right.weight+(diff*-1)
```

Basically here you have some node. Then you check left/right node and update the correct one. We could move it to your class responsible for node

```
class Node:
    def balance(self):
        # diff is not needed, as you just set up left to right or otherwise
        if root.right
           root.right.balance()
        if root.left:
           root.left.balance()
        if root.left and root.right:
            if root.right.weight > root.left.weight:
                root.left.weight=root.right.weight
            else:
                root.right.weight=root.left.weight
```

And now your code could be shortened to:

```
root.balance()
```

Comment: this only for one level  what about level 2 (root. left. left  .... etc )

Comment: I mean if you focus on the def method,,, it's executing left,right  in all level (1,2 )

Comment: so do you search for a way to call it on every node?

Comment: I updated an aswer (your example calls it only for two levels), if you want to run in recursevily, you can add that in `balance` function.

Comment: yes,,, in every level will compare the left and right,, (if one is higher than the other),,, then it will go to the next level (left.left.weight ) and compare it with (left. right.weight .)..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not fully clear in terms what you are trying to achieve plus there is no return condition so assuming the unknown I would try to achieve something like this using recursion:

```
def new_weights(counter = 0, right_weight, left_weight):
    if counter < 3: 
        diff = right_weight - left_weight
        
        if diff> 0:
            left_weight += diff
        else:
            right_weight += (diff * -1)
        counter += 1
        return new_weights(counter, right_weight, left_weight)
    
    else:
        return diff
```